# Update Progressbar on UI while inside loop

Tags: android, loops

For once and for all I want to accomplish this.
I have a string request that looks like this

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MASTER_LINK,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray received_data = obj.getJSONArray("received");
                        if (received_data.length() == 0) {
                            /* TODO : Check what to do in this universe later */
                        } else {

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", current_email);
            return params;
        }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

What the code above will do is to create a request from a php file using `email` parameter
whats next is that it will create a csv file from `SELECT` and after that it will return a
json array called `received` with a data called `done_cus`

After that if the value has been returned it will download that file and that code is this

```
if (done_process.toString().matches("done_cus")) {
    FilePathname_CUS = sdCardDirectory + "/" + for_current_email + "_" + param_dim_customer + ".csv";
    file_link = download_file + for_current_email + "_" + param_dim_customer + ".csv";
    DownloadFilesname(FilePathname_CUS, file_link);
    row_count = row_count + count_row(FilePathname_CUS);
    count_customer = 1;
    Log.e("Downloaded", "Customer List");
}
```

Please take a look at this `count_row` what it will do is to count how many rows does that file has so lets
say we have 1000 rows so if i have 5 then with each 1k rows then 5k

this is the next that i will do i will insert that in my SQLLite

```
File file = new File(FilePathname_CUS);
CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader();
try (CsvParser csvParser = csvReader.parse(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    CsvRow row;
    if (count_row(FilePathname_CUS) != 0) {
        myDb.delete_customer(current_email);
        while ((row = csvParser.nextRow()) != null) {
            myDb.insert_customer(
                    row.getField(0),
                    row.getField(1),
                    row.getField(2),
                    row.getField(3),
                    row.getField(4),
                    row.getField(5),
                    row.getField(6),
                    row.getField(7),
                    row.getField(8),
                    row.getField(9),
                    row.getField(10)
            );
            Log.e("Inserting", "" + row.getField(0));
            index++;
            p = (float) index / (float) row_count;
            p = p * (float) 100;
        }

    } else {

    }
}
```

Notice this part

```
index++;
p = (float) index / (float) row_count;
p = p * (float) 100;
```

it is like a percentage like this `99%` now after all the explanation here is my question.

How can I my progress bar with that value?

Here is my progressbar

`mProgressAnimation.setProgress("Value of the v")`;

because what i see is that the progress bar will only update after the loop.. How about during the loop?

Here is the whole code

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MASTER_LINK,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray received_data = obj.getJSONArray("received");
                        if (received_data.length() == 0) {
                            /* TODO : Check what to do in this universe later */
                        } else {
                            if (done_process.toString().matches("done_cus")) {
                                FilePathname_CUS = sdCardDirectory + "/" + for_current_email + "_" + param_dim_customer + ".csv";
                                file_link = download_file + for_current_email + "_" + param_dim_customer + ".csv";
                                DownloadFilesname(FilePathname_CUS, file_link);
                                row_count = row_count + count_row(FilePathname_CUS);
                                count_customer = 1;
                                Log.e("Downloaded", "Customer List");
                            }

                            File file = new File(FilePathname_CUS);
                            CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader();
                            try (CsvParser csvParser = csvReader.parse(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                                CsvRow row;
                                if (count_row(FilePathname_CUS) != 0) {
                                    myDb.delete_customer(current_email);
                                    while ((row = csvParser.nextRow()) != null) {
                                        myDb.insert_customer(
                                                row.getField(0),
                                                row.getField(1),
                                                row.getField(2),
                                                row.getField(3),
                                                row.getField(4),
                                                row.getField(5),
                                                row.getField(6),
                                                row.getField(7),
                                                row.getField(8),
                                                row.getField(9),
                                                row.getField(10)
                                        );
                                        Log.e("Inserting", "" + row.getField(0));
                                        index++;
                                        p = (float) index / (float) row_count;
                                        p = p * (float) 100;
                                        mProgressAnimation.setProgress(p); //this must be update the progress bar
                                    }

                                } else {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", current_email);
            return params;
        }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: When are you calling `setProgress()`?

Comment: well my target is to call it inside the loop

Comment: But where is that loop? Where is that `if` statement that calls the loop function?

Comment: im sure you will ask that so i updated my code

Comment: I think even if you find a way to update the Progressbar you will run into ANR error. Because the onResponse method runs on Background thread and you can not update UI elements with Background thread. Use an  AsyncTask

Comment: im aware of that and i cannot reach more that what i have to do because its hard to made and i hope i will not get those ANR

Comment: I'm confused about what you're doing. You don't even have anything asynchronous in your code.

Comment: well im sorry with that because this is my first time doing android programming so im not aware with that

Comment: What is the problem currently and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: @earthw0rmjim my target is to update my progressbar to how many percent while on the loop what happens is the it does compute but the progress bar updates at the end

Comment: @myownemail that's because: **1.** The listener method `onResponse(String response)` is typically called on main thread.  **2.** `CsvReader` and `for` loop won't take much time to process, its quick enough that you can't notice the progress updates until at the end.

Comment: @AdilSoomro i hope there is other way so i can update the progress bar

Comment: maybe 10-50 ms thats enough i think

Comment: @myownemail I think you're confusing between **1.** time it took to do a network request and get response with **2.** time it took to parse and insert into db. The network request time is lot more significant than the parsing time. You should consider showing progress for network request. Additionally, if you really have to show progress on parsing only, then you need to do the parsing in background, and introduce fake wait to mimic the progress update which is not advisable.

Comment: @AdilSoomro i see but i dont know what to do. i hope you can guide me with that

Comment: @pskink a progress that will show that the loop is working. that there is progress because this records is consist of thousands maybe what you suggest is ok i will just adjust that

Comment: @pskink and others Good Morning.. Any guess or tricks with my question still struggling :(

Comment: actually depends on the data that it will be looped, am i right?

Comment: @pskink good morning any updates? sorry if i might disturb you

Comment: yes sir most likely that

Comment: @pskink  am trying to `AsyncTask` but it does not work on `VolleySingleTon` so i enclosed it inside a function but i dont know how to return the value of loop to the `AsyncTask`

Comment: ok sir im done and i really dont know what your saying about "how long wiil it take"   what do i need to know to answer that

Comment: @pksink sorry for being disrespect it is my first time making this app. What should i need to look in my code to answer your question of how long it will take